# Is the speed of light slow down around gravitational body?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, gravitational-lensing

In gravitational lensing effect, there are two types of time delay; geometric delay, gravitational delay.

gravitational time delay is not caused by "distance", and speed is "distance/time". the distance is not change but time is expansion, so I came to a conclusion that "light of speed is slow down around gravitational body".

I want to ask that 'Principle of Constancy of Light Velocity' is not applied in "general relativity"?

I guess the reason is the main assumption of special relativity(The laws of physics are invariant -that is, identical- in all inertial frames of reference -that is, frames of reference with no acceleration-, wikipedia "special relativity") is only applied in inertial frame.

Am I correct?

If It's correct, I have a one more question.
If there is the spaceship which is accelerating to speed of light,
Does the light which emitted from the spaceship have different speed of light with '299,792km/s'?

Comment: In gravitational lensing, speed of light doesn't change, only does its direction.

Comment: this may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59502/does-gravity-slow-the-speed-that-light-travels